# Error in restoring site collection on the same port

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, restore

I have taken the site collection backup and moved into a another server and tried to restore it. and its worked.

Now, i am trying to create another site collection with the same back up file on the same port number web application.
But it throws me an erro, already an site collection exists

Comment: Site collections have unique ID's. You can only have one, so you need to create a new site collection and restore the site collection backup to the new one (with a new ID).

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111714/restore-a-copy-of-the-same-site-collection-insdie-the-same-web-application

Answer (score 1):

When you take backup and you restore it same web app it will not work as it will have ID. But if you will restore it in new content database it will work fine (even on same web app)